# How to prevent view from moving up extra space when using keyboard with multiple text fields

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, textfield

This is the code so far for moving my view up when I press on a textfield  and presenting my keyboard. However, since I have two textfields in one view, whenever i press the second textfield, the view moves up the keyboard height again so the view is way off the screen. How do I prevent the user from pressing the second textfield when the first textfield is present. I am using the function touchesbegan for the user to hide the keyboard when anywhere on the view is pressed.

**When first textfield is pressed:**
[image]

**When second textfield is pressed:**
[image]

Here is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true;

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){
    view.endEditing(true)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true;
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)


}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] = sender.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.size
    self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
}



func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] = sender.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.size
    let offset: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.size

    if keyboardSize.height == offset.height {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        })
    } else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height - offset.height
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: You could set a bool value for when the first textfield begins editing, then check if that bool value is set to yes in your keyboardwillshow notification to decide if you can begin editing the second textfield or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out this awesome library to do this perfectly. 
https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

That should avoid any heavy lifting on your part.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the TPKeyboardAvoiding views that rikola suggested but I think there is a simpler solution to your problem that lies in your calculations in your `keyboardWillShow(_:)` and `keyboardWillHide(_:)` methods.

```
func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] = sender.userInfo!
    let animationDuration: Double = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]!.doubleValue

    UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    })
}

func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] = sender.userInfo!
    let endSize: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.size
    let animationDuration: Double = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]!.doubleValue

    UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.view.frame.origin.y = endSize.height
    })
}
```

Notice the differences here. This code simply looks at the frame where the keyboard will end up using `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`, grabs the duration that the animation will take `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey` and animates your view to match it. The problem with your code was that you are performing `-=` and `+=` operations, which means that the method is dependent on the previous state of the view. In the code I posted the method is state-independent and can be called as many times in a row as the system feels like and it will still behave correctly.

Also is also bonus points for completion to be had here if you grab the `UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey` from `userInfo` and use that animation curve in your animation options to make sure that the view matches exactly the animation the keyboard is performing. That being said, I've never found it necessary to do so.

Comment: Thanks alot. The only thing that was different was that I had to make the endsize.height negative to move the view up instead of down. Otherwise thanks for the advice, it worked perfectly!

Comment: Cheers man, can you accept the answer if it worked for you? Thanks!